# Merging dataframes based on a column 's values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of dataframes `(df_t)`. Each dataframe has the same  exactly same two columns but different number of rows . I merged all the dataframes to one dataframe.
However, I would like to use `(df_A [label_1])` as a reference and drop the `(df_B [label_2]) (df_A [label_3])` like in the example

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0.5, 1, 0.5],'label_1': ['-1', '1', '-1', '1']})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1.5, 2.3],'label_2': ['-1', '1','-1']})
df_C = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2.1, 5.5],'label_3': ['-1', '1']})
df_t = {'1': df_A, '2': df_B, '3': df_C}

#d = { k: v.set_index('label') for k, v in df_t.items()}
dfx = pd.concat(df_t, axis=1)

dfx.columns = dfx.columns.droplevel(0)
```

[image]

Comment: So you want to have two columns in the final dataframe?

Comment: I want to have three A,A,A and Label_1

Comment: `pd.concat([df_A,df_B["A"],df_C["A"]], axis = 1)` try something like this.

Comment: This one doesn't take (df_A [label_1]) as a reference, in the case of changing df_B [label_2] it will not sort the numbers to write labels.